# Laravel server not starting

Tags: php, laravel, frameworks

I have a fresh installed laravel app and when i run `php artisan serve` it shows me the server information but when i go to that server it gives a cant be reach error. I am not running Vagrant just MAMP but it used to work before. I did tried to install Vagrant in the past and it didn't work that is why i came back to MAMP only. I read something about generating a key with `php artisan key:generate` which didn't work. Any help is appreciated.

This is the command I am using and the result

```
$ php artisan serve
Laravel development server started: <http://127.0.0.1:8000>
```

Comment: any error message?.

Comment: How did you installed Laravel? And what do you see when go to `http://127.0.0.1:8000`

Comment: `php artisan serve` and MAMP are two separate servers, `artisan serve` will do something like `php -S localhost:8000` (built in PHP web server). You use one or the other

Answer (score 1):

try to uninstall the antivirus if you have one ,in my case i uninstall avast ,reboot OS and it works for me .

Comment: Uninstalling an antivirus program is not an usable solution. You leave your computer unprotected.